# Is Ubuntu 14.04 using eglibc or glibc?

Tags: glibc

I have an ARM chip CM-FX6 using Ubuntu 12.04LTS (armel) using the linux image provided by the vendor Compulab. It is using eglibc.

Recently I have to install some sdk for video streaming from ethernet that the manufacturer specifically said eglibc is not supported. They said that I should use a distribution which uses glibc.

So my question is, does Ubuntu 14.04 use eglibc, or glibc? 
What are my options here, in order to get my ubuntu system working with the sdk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is using eglibc.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc) You might compile `glibc` yourself, or you could start using [Debian `sid`](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/glibc).

Comment: Meaning 14.04 is eglibc, right?

Comment: @lppier Yes. I don't think Ubuntu will convert to `glibc` until 15.04.